# Funcionamento da lista de reputação

Tags: suporte, reputação

Como funciona cada coluna da [lista de reputação](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/273/)?

Usando como exemplo a imagem abaixo do meu usuário na [lista mensal](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/273/month/pt-stackoverflow):

[image: usuário na lista de reputação mensal]

- Como funciona o *change*?

  - Por que estou com `-1`, sendo que todo o resto está positivo?
- Como funciona o *total reputation*?

  - Por que na reputação do [perfil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/42085?tab=reputation) estou agora com `540`, mas na lista mensal o *total reputation* é `490`?
- Como funciona o *month reputation*?

  - Por que estou com `169`, mas se somar no [meu perfil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/42085?tab=reputation) está `219`?

Comment: Desculpa se é uma lista óbvia pro resto dos usuários, mas eu não entendi bem e não achei se tem algum lugar explicando.

Comment: Obs: Enquanto escrevia a pergunta eu pensei o que pode ser o _change_, ele é a sua mudança de colocação no rank, certo? No meu caso eu perdi rank na reputação mensal, ou seja, cai de 43 para 42.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Acertou nos comentários. O *change* é a mundaça de posição no *ranking*.

Esta lista é atualizada de tempos em tempos, então ela pode estar defasada.